# using revealing module pattern in javascript creates problems as data no longer global

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This following is a minimised version of my earlier code which was working..

```
var data = [mydata];
var appscope = function() {
    function col(c) {
        var self = this;
        this.view = ko.observable(false);
        this.view.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            vm.updateCol();
        });
    }
    var myModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.viewdata = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.updateCol = function() {
            console.log("updatecol called")
        };
    };
    var vm = new myModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
}();
```

In the above code vm.updatecol works as vm is global as far as appscope is concerned. Also data is global..

Now I'm trying to use revealing module pattern and changed the code to as below..

```
var appscope = function() {
    var that = this;

    function col(c) {
        var self = this;
        this.view = ko.observable(false);
        this.view.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            //  vm.updateCol(); no longer works....
            //that.appscope.myModel().updatecol(); throws error in myModel
        });
    }
    var myModel = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.viewdata = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.target=ko.observable(null);
        self.target(new col([]));
        self.updateCol = function() {
            console.log("updatecol called")
        };
    };
    return {
        myModel: myModel
    };
}();
(function(appscope) {
    var vm = new appscope.myModel([mydata]);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
})(appscope);
```

In the above code vm.updatecol does not work as vm is out of scope. I even tried that.appscope.myModel().updatecol() but that tries to recreate myModel and as data is not present throws other errors.

How do i solve this.
All help is sincerely appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: *"using revealing module pattern in javascript creates problems as data no longer global"* No no no, it **solves** problems as data is no longer global. :-)

Comment: I've fixed it for you this time, but when asking for help, please take the time to format your code with consistent, clear indentation/formatting.

Comment: In myModel add the line self.target=ko.observable(null); self,target(new col([]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! You've successfully decoupled `col` from `myModel` and `vm`. That's mostly a good thing. But, since you still want to call `updateCol` when `col`'s `view` changes, you do need to hook them up somehow.

You have three options:

1. Pass a reference to the `myModel` instance into `col` when creating it
2. Leave it to `myModel` to subscribe to `col`'s `view`
3. Revisit the entire structure

This feels like #3 to me, but it's impossible to say without more context.

Example of #1:

```
var appscope = function() {
    var that = this;

    function col(c, model) {                      // ***
        var self = this;
        this.view = ko.observable(false);
        this.view.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            model.updateCol();                    // ***
        });
    }
    var myModel = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.viewdata = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.target=ko.observable(null);
        self.target(new col([], self));           // ***
        self.updateCol = function() {
            console.log("updatecol called")
        };
    };
    return {
        myModel: myModel
    };
}();
(function(appscope) {
    var vm = new appscope.myModel([mydata]);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
})(appscope);
```

Example of #2:

```
var appscope = function() {
    var that = this;

    function col(c) {
        var self = this;
        this.view = ko.observable(false);
        // *** Not subscribing here
    }
    var myModel = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.viewdata = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.target=ko.observable(null);
        var c = new col([]);                   // ***
        self.target(c);                        // ***
        c.view.subscribe(function(newValue) {  // ***
            self.updateCol();                  // ***
        });                                    // ***
        self.updateCol = function() {
            console.log("updatecol called")
        };
    };
    return {
        myModel: myModel
    };
}();
(function(appscope) {
    var vm = new appscope.myModel([mydata]);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
})(appscope);
```

This second approach has an issue that you've made `target` an observable. If `target` can really change, we need to do some subscription management, which is part of why I lean toward #3 above:

```
var appscope = function() {
    var that = this;

    function col(c) {
        var self = this;
        this.view = ko.observable(false);
        // *** Not subscribing here
    }
    var myModel = function(data) {
        var viewSub;                                        // ***
        var self = this;
        self.viewdata = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.target=ko.observable(null);
        var c = new col([]);                                // ***
        self.target(c);                                     // ***
        subScribeCol(c);                                    // ***
        self.target.subscribe(function(newCol) {            // ***
            viewSub.dispose();                              // ***
            subcribeCol();                                  // ***
        });                                                 // ***
        self.updateCol = function() {
            console.log("updatecol called")
        };
        function subscribeCol(c) {
            viewSub = c.view.subscribe(function(newValue) { // ***
                self.updateCol();                           // ***
            });                                             // ***
        }
    };
    return {
        myModel: myModel
    };
}();
(function(appscope) {
    var vm = new appscope.myModel([mydata]);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
})(appscope);
```